# Улучшить текст об использовании визитки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, настройки-профиля, визитка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

> Просто скопируйте и вставьте нижеприведённый фрагмент HTML-кода в то
>   место, где вы хотите продемонстрировать свою визитку на Stack Overflow
>   на русском

В оригинале там:

> Simply copy and paste the below HTML snippet wherever you want to show
>   off your Stack Overflow flair

Т.е, речь о том, что вы на другом сайте можете использовать HTML-код.

Текущий же перевод, по крайней мере у меня, понимается как "продемонстрировать визитку на сайте Stack Overflow", а не где-то ещё.

Или так только у меня и остальными текст воспринимается однозначно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, почему @alexolut не запостил ответом, но утверждён его вариант:

> Просто скопируйте и вставьте фрагмент HTML-кода на тех ресурсах, где
>   вы хотите продемонстрировать свою визитку сайта $siteName$

Comment: Это не мой вариант, это адаптация вашего ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/9345

Предлагаю:

> Просто скопируйте и вставьте фрагмент HTML-кода на тех ресурсах, где
>   вы хотите продемонстрировать свою $siteName$ визитку:

Comment: А причем тут `$siteName$`? Почему бы не оставить просто "визитку"?

Comment: @AntonSorokin в оригинале `Simply copy and paste the below HTML snippet wherever you want to show off your $siteName$ flair:`.... Поэтому логичней оставить.

Comment: @AntonSorokin это шаблон для строк перевода, переменные подставляются в зависимости от сайта. От этого никуда не деться )=